# Android ClassNotFoundException Using GoogleMaps API V2

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, classnotfoundexception

I'm developing a simple app utilizing the google maps api v2. I added the google-play-services_lib to the project correctly, and I believe my Manifest file is correct, but I get the following error:

```
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): Process: com.example.unitygame7, PID: 7610
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:106)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at com.example.unitygame7.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-05 19:17:37.709: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.unitygame7"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
    android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.NFC"
    android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SOCIAL_STREAM"
    android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"
    android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.unitygame7.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.unitygame7.TrackingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tracking" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.unitygame7.MapActivityty"
        android:label="You're Awesome, Oak" >
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCvTweV4Iv8VrXA90fAC6_y0_1UUcBiOco" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need reference a Compat Support Library. Please take a look to [Android Developer Center](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

If you are using Eclipse:

1. Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the SDK Manager.
2. Create a libs/ directory in the root of your application project.
3. Copy the JAR file from your Android SDK installation directory (e.g., /extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar) into your application's project libs/ directory.
4. Right click the JAR file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path.

Otherwise if you use Android Studio:

1. Add dependency :compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+' to build.gradle file on your module folder.
2. Ensure that appcompat jar are on External Libraries folder.

And on your style.xml file set: android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat".

Comment: Hey, I tried that and thank you very much my app ran, but now it is crashing right after launch. You have already been very helpful but if you know what this error message means it would be super awesome thanks. BTW I use Eclipse.

Comment: Set on your style.xml file android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat".